How to properly configure Entity Attribute Value pattern in Django?
I have a product model:
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount = models.IntegerField() # stands for percentage
    count = models.IntegerField()
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Now, I want to implement Entity Attribute Value pattern, as different products can have different specifications. I understood the traditional way of EAV. But I read in wikipedia that postgresql has jsonb column type and this allows performance improvements by factors of a thousand or more over traditional EAV table designs. My database is postgresql. So what is the best practice to implement EAV (or dynamic set relationship with attributes)? Should I just add like:
class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    specifications = models.JSONField()

And also I want to handle price and count (in stock) differently for each variant, let's say there are 10 shoes with size 10 and color red which price is 100 dollars and 2 shoes with size 9 and color blue which price is 120 dollars.
